# WxPython Bind events to TextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a TextCtrl and two events. One is bind the other is not

```
    self.rtb = wx.TextCtrl(self, ID_RTB, size=wx.Size(400,200),
                          style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_RICH2)

    wx.EVT_KEY_UP(self.rtb, self.OnRtbKeyUp)
    self.rtb.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_PASTE, self.OnPaste)
```

**What is the difference?** It seems that both events works fine.

I've read about Binding all sources explain how to use. None explains the difference between event that isn't bind to event that is bind.

Comment: no difference the second version is typically prefered ... the first one could be rewritten as `self.rtb.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP,self.OnRtbKeyUp)`

Comment: if it's preferred there has to be a reason...? I'm assuming both code aren't implemented the same way. Even if in the final result both do the same task there could be differences in how they achieve it.

Comment: its preferred because its considered more readable, and thus more pythonic ... in older version of wx (And perhaps other languages) the widget.Bind method is not supported ... so usually you see the other form in legacy code ... both methods of binding are supported and the underlying function is the same (it calls `wxEVT_MY_CMD_EVT(widget,callback)` in the c++ code .... ) I'll see if i can find the actual source code via googling (its open source)

Comment: As I recall, I think the first one is the original wxWidgets method of binding and the latter is the Python way...or perhaps just the new method in general.